# Filter lines based on strings with nested conditions

Tags: python, functional-programming, nested

I have lines of data from a csv file, the first line stored are the headers. For example:

```
first line -> [a,b,c,d,e]

second line -> [0,1,2,1,2]

third line -> [4,2,4,1,5]
```

Plus, i have strings with conditions related to the data in the following format:

condition = (((a = d) OR (a = c)) AND (c < e))

The output should be only line 3. How can I evaluate this conditions, and separate all the nested subconditions? I was thinking on a recursive function, reading through the parenthesis, but i have a mess in my code :(. Thanks for the answers and sorry my bad english!

PS: I wouldn't like to use pandas, or csv libraries 
PS2: The condition above is just a example, there could be another more nested conditions like ((((a = d) AND (c > e)) OR (b = c)) AND (e < d)), or sometimes, simply (a = d)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a quick solution:

```
from itertools import ifilter

with open('input.csv', 'r') as fi:
    lines = ((rawline, map(int, rawline.split(','))) for rawline in  fi.readlines()[1:])
    results = ifilter(lambda (_, fds): (fds[0] == fds[3] or fds[0] == fds[2]) and (fds[2] < fds[4]), lines)
    for (rawline, _) in results:
        print rawline
```

With input.csv being:

```
a,b,c,d,e
0,1,2,1,2
4,2,4,1,5
```

The result output is:

```
4,2,4,1,5
```

**Update**: a shorter/compact implementation:

```
from itertools import ifilter

with open('input.csv', 'r') as fi:
    results = ifilter(
        lambda fds: (fds[0] == fds[3] or fds[0] == fds[2]) and (fds[2] < fds[4]),
        (map(int, rawline.split(',')) for rawline in fi.readlines()[1:]))
    for fields in results:
        print ','.join(map(str,fields))
```

Comment: Nice!, but i was looking for something general, i forgot to mention that the condition was only a example between many posibilities.

Comment: @Zealot, please check my another answer

Answer (score 0):

*Better to create a new answer as the requirement has been updated/changed*

The quickest solution for evaluating the conditions of string format is to use built-in function [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). In this way, you don't have to do the heavy/unaffordable parsing([lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [syntactic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing))

Here is the sample code:

```
from itertools import ifilter

condition1 = '(((a = d) OR (a = c)) AND (c < e))'

def evalCondition(condition, *args):
    '''
    1) if you have condition format follow python grammar, then you don't need below replacement
    2) assume there is no '>=' or '<=', otherwise, you have to use more sophisticated replacement method e.g. using regular exppression
    '''
    condition = condition.replace('=', '==').replace('OR', 'or').replace('AND', 'and')

    a,b,c,d,e = args
    return eval(condition)

with open('input.csv', 'r') as fi:
    results = ifilter(
        lambda fields: evalCondition(condition1, *fields),
        (map(int, rawline.split(',')) for rawline in fi.readlines()[1:]))
    for fields in results:
        print ','.join(map(str,fields))
```

With input.csv being:

```
a,b,c,d,e
0,1,2,1,2
4,2,4,1,5
```

The result output is:

```
4,2,4,1,5
```